# Super key stops responding randomly on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04

well basically after a while super key stops responding altogether. I can't lock window or get it do anything.
Any idea on what might be causing this?

Using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: When that key stops responding, do other keys stop as well? Does the Super key not respond in other environments such as Ubuntu Live or Windows? If so, I think you might just have a dirty Super key preventing contact.

Comment: What do you mean by "lock window"? What do you mean by "get it to do anything"?, i.e., what is "it"? Clarify your question and describe the symptoms precisely to increase your chance on a good answer.